# change one key-value in map columns in hive table via HQL

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql, hiveql

I have a Hive table whose schema is as below, the `col` is of `map` type:

```
select
    col
from table

col
{"name":"abc", "value":"val_1"}
```

What I need to do is change the `val_1` to `val_2` and create another table from it.

```
create table table_2 as
select
    col -- TODO: need to do something here
from table
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What is the data type of `col`?

Comment: it's a `map` type. @DuduMarkovitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with t as (select map("name","abc","value","val_1") as col)
select  map("name",col["name"],"value","val_2") as col
from    t
```

---

```
+--------------------------------+
|              col               |
+--------------------------------+
| {"name":"abc","value":"val_2"} |
+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: Since this is only a sample question, the real one will have dynamic key-value pairs in `col` (for sure there will be at least key `value`, for the key `name` and the rest, it's dynamic), is there any general way to implement? Thanks man!

Comment: Jason, there is a way (done that), but it is ugly as hell and has some limitations. I would write a UDF for that

Comment: Thanks man, I've tried to write a scala function and registered it to UDF already. Cheers :)